# Requisição "Curl" no meu servidor está com erro no certificado SSL

Tags: php, libcurl, ssl

Estou realizando uma requisição Curl com PHP na minha hospedagem.
Porém se deixo o parâmetro "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" verdadeiro, a requisição me retorna o erro "**cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate**".

Porém meu site está com ssl ativo e funcionando normalmente.

Como faço para ativar esse ssl nas respostas das requisiçoes curl na minha hospedagem?

Meu código Curl de exemplo:

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://site.com.br',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: text/plain'
            ),
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o parâmetro -k? Exemplo: `curl https://site.com.br -k`. [ref](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-k)

Comment: Provavelmente, não é quem responde que é o problema, mas quem faz a requisição. O TLS/SSL funciona baseado em confiança de autoridade, uma autoridade (como a DigiCert, IdenTrust, GlobalSign...) assina a chave e gera um certificado. Portanto, quem estabelece a conexão (o seu cURL) deve também confiar na mesma autoridade, e para isso ele tem que saber as chaves públicas. Em geral, isso é chama "CA-Bundle". Ele tem a chave pública de todas as autoridades que são confiáveis (por um criterio um tanto quanto arbitrário). Enfim, configure o CA-Bundle, como mencionado no link anterior (duplicada).